# How to use XSLT for Grouping and Sum

Tags: xslt, bpel

How to use XSLT for the following situation **without using `xsl:for-each-group`**

My requirement: If Field1 .. Field6 of Iteration Matches Field1 .. Field6 of any iteration in the group, then we need to sum the amount and take lowest ID of the group.

***Input***

```
<Shipment>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Field1>abcd</Field1>
    <Field2>1234</Field2>
    <Field3>efgh</Field4>
    <Field4>5678</Field4>
    <Field5>ijkl</Field5>
    <Field6>90mn</Field6>
    <Amount>200.00</Amount>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Field1>abcd</Field1>
    <Field2>1234</Field2>
    <Field3>efgh</Field4>
    <Field4>5678</Field4>
    <Field5>ijkl</Field5>
    <Field6>90mn</Field6>
    <Amount>600.00</Amount>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Field1>1234</Field1>
    <Field2>abcd</Field2>
    <Field3>efgh</Field4>
    <Field4>5678</Field4>
    <Field5>2345</Field5>
    <Field6>80mn</Field6>
    <Amount>600.00</Amount>
</Shipment>
```

***Expected OutPut***

```
<Shipment>
    <ID>1</ID>  
    <Field1>abcd</Field1>
    <Field2>1234</Field2>
    <Field3>efgh</Field4>
    <Field4>5678</Field4>
    <Field5>ijkl</Field5>
    <Field6>90mn</Field6>
    <Amount>800.00</Amount> 
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Field1>1234</Field1>
    <Field2>abcd</Field2>
    <Field3>efgh</Field4>
    <Field4>5678</Field4>
    <Field5>2345</Field5>
    <Field6>80mn</Field6>
    <Amount>600.00</Amount>
</Shipment>
```

Comment: Your input isn't valid: <Field3> has a </Field4> closing element

Comment: If you cannot use `xsl:for-each-group` this isn't an XSLT 2.0 question at all -- the title is very misleading.

Comment: The provided XML fragment is severely malformed. Please, *edit* the question and correct.

Answer (score 1):

**The requirement not to use `xsl:for-each-group` clearly indicates that an XSLT 2.0 processor isn't available**.

**Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kAllFields" match="Shipment" use=
 "concat(Field1,'+',Field2,'+',Field3,'+',Field4,'+',Field5,'+',Field6)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Shipment
     [not(generate-id()
     =
      generate-id(key('kAllFields',
                      concat(Field1,'+',Field2,'+',Field3,'+',Field4,'+',Field5,'+',Field6))[1]))]
 "/>

 <xsl:template match="Shipment">
  <xsl:variable name="vGroup" select=
  "key('kAllFields', concat(Field1,'+',Field2,'+',Field3,'+',Field4,'+',Field5,'+',Field6))"/>

  <Shipment>
    <ID>
      <xsl:call-template name="min">
        <xsl:with-param name="pItems" select="$vGroup/ID"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </ID>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(), 'Field')]"/>
    <Amount><xsl:value-of select="sum($vGroup/Amount)"/></Amount>
  </Shipment>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="min">
  <xsl:param name="pItems" select="/.."/>
  <xsl:param name="pDataType" select="'number'"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$pItems">
    <xsl:sort data-type="{$pDataType}"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() =1"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided severely malformed fragment -- corrected and wrapped into a single top element to make it a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <Shipment>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Field1>abcd</Field1>
        <Field2>1234</Field2>
        <Field3>efgh</Field3>
        <Field4>5678</Field4>
        <Field5>ijkl</Field5>
        <Field6>90mn</Field6>
        <Amount>200.00</Amount>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Field1>abcd</Field1>
        <Field2>1234</Field2>
        <Field3>efgh</Field3>
        <Field4>5678</Field4>
        <Field5>ijkl</Field5>
        <Field6>90mn</Field6>
        <Amount>600.00</Amount>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Field1>1234</Field1>
        <Field2>abcd</Field2>
        <Field3>efgh</Field3>
        <Field4>5678</Field4>
        <Field5>2345</Field5>
        <Field6>80mn</Field6>
        <Amount>600.00</Amount>
    </Shipment>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <Shipment>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Field1>abcd</Field1>
      <Field2>1234</Field2>
      <Field3>efgh</Field3>
      <Field4>5678</Field4>
      <Field5>ijkl</Field5>
      <Field6>90mn</Field6>
      <Amount>800</Amount>
   </Shipment>
   <Shipment>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Field1>1234</Field1>
      <Field2>abcd</Field2>
      <Field3>efgh</Field3>
      <Field4>5678</Field4>
      <Field5>2345</Field5>
      <Field6>80mn</Field6>
      <Amount>600</Amount>
   </Shipment>
</t>
```

Comment: Dimitre, Thank you verymuch for the response. Sorry for the malformed xml, Classic example of typo errors. I will update you as fit this in to the grand scheme of things, and test it in the bpel process.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Can you please tell me how can we achive that using for-each-group ???? i am stuck

Comment: @UsmanRiaz, As it is said in this answer, one must have and use an XSLT 2.0 (or higher version) processor. For example, there are free, even open source editions of Saxon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a separator that isn't used in Field1 through Field6.

```
<xsl:param name="separator" select="'-'"/>
<xsl:template match="/shipments">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Shipment" group-by="concat(Field1,$separator,Field2,$separator,Field3,$separator,Field4,$separator,Field5,$separator,Field6)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[ID=min(current-group()/ID)]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

W[orking example](http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Y3)

Comment: Joepie, Thank you for response. I am unable to use for-each-group and template match in BPEL 2.0 specification. it is only allowing me template "/" and template name